# Why is this area apparently unpopulated in the great Buenos Aires, what is it?

Tags: geography

I'm not sure if I can ask this question here but it is the only Stack Exchange community where I saw the tag Geography. I was reading about the great Buenos Aires and I saw this night satellital picture. There is this big area apparently unpopulated or with little population surrounded by the metropolis. What is it? Why is it apparently unpopulated?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“[Campo de Mayo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2g9G.jpg) is a military base located in Greater Buenos Aires, Argentina, 30 km (19 mi) northwest of Buenos Aires”. 
                                               [Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2g9G.jpg)[wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2g9G.jpg)[image: Campo de mayo]